# Magento2: Decimal Price in Chinese traditional language display [object Object] instead of dot

Tags: magento-2.1, price

I have multi language store. default language is English. there are few products have decimal price.

when i switch language to Chinese it is working fine.But when i switch to Chinese traditional the  **[object Object]**  appears instead dot in decimal price.

for example: price: $69.95 in English when i switch language to Chinese traditional the price will look like Price: $69[object Object]95

i really wanna remove this , need . how to do that.?

Comment: Have you got any solution for this issue ?

Comment: Yes, It language tranlation problem

Comment: How you resolve this issue, Can you please post the answer for the solution.

Comment: Present i don't have accessto that site.I did changes view phtml file getting product price and directly displaying using formatting price. After that enabled production mode deployed static content It worked.